# static массив объектов в классе

Tags: java, массивы, ооп, объекты

Хочу создать массив объектов дочерних классов для неявного обращения к нему, но ругается на то что этот массив является static.

```
public class Product {
    protected int id;
    private static int storageVolume;

    Product (int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void getStats(){
        System.out.println(id);
    }
    public void getId(){
        System.out.println(id);
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static void createStorage(int storageVolume){
        this.storageVolume = storageVolume;
        static Product[] storage = new Product[this.storageVolume];
    }
}
```

> 'com.autasalon.Product.this' cannot be referenced from a static context

> Modifier 'static' not allowed here

> 'com.autasalon.Product.this' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Правильно статический меод не может обратиться к экземпляру

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответ я разобрался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Модификатор **static** означает, что к вашему массиву можно будет обратиться не через объект типа, а через сам тип.

Но всё, что создается в методе, будет уничтожено, когда метод покинет стек.

Из этого следует вывод, что модификатор **static** нельзя использовать в методе, так как **static** переменная должна существовать, пока существует тип, то есть **static** переменная должна являться полем типа.

И второй момент - **static** метод вызывается через тип, а не объект, поэтому внутри **static** метода не может быть **this**.

Answer (score 1):

```
static Product[] storage;
public static void createStorage(int storageVolume){
    Product.storageVolume = storageVolume;
    storage = new Product[Product.storageVolume];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Статический метод не может обратиться к экземпляру класса, и вообще к не статическим данным

```
public static void createStorage(int storageVolume){
    static Product[] storage = new Product[storageVolume];
    ......
}
```

либо как-то так

```
public static void createStorage(int storageVolume){
    Product.storageVolume = storageVolume;
    static Product[] storage = new Product[storageVolume];
}
```